# Scrapy regexp for sitemap_follow

Tags: python, scrapy

if you have a sitemap.xml containing:

```
abc.com/sitemap-1.xml
abc.com/sitemap-2.xml
abc.com/image-sitemap.xml
```

how do i write sitemap_follow to read only the sitemap-xxx sitemaps and not image-sitemap.xml?
I tried with

```
^sitemap
```

with no luck. What should I do? negate "image"? How?

Edit:
Scrapy code:

```
self._follow = [regex(x) for x in self.sitemap_follow]
```

and

```
if any(x.search(loc) for x in self._follow):
```

The regex is applied to the whole url. The only way I see a solution without modifying Scrapy is to have a Scraper just for abc.com and add it to the regex OR just add the / to the regex

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question naively and directly I offer this code. In other words, I can match each of the items in the sitemap index file using the regex `^.$`.

```
>>> import re
>>> sitemap_index_file_content = [
... 'abc.com/sitemap-1.xml',
... 'abc.com/sitemap-2.xml',
... 'abc.com/image-sitemap.xml'
... ]
>>> for s in sitemap_index_file_content:
...     m = re.match(r'^.*$', s)
...     if m:
...         m.group()
... 
'abc.com/sitemap-1.xml'
'abc.com/sitemap-2.xml'
'abc.com/image-sitemap.xml'
```

This implies that you would set `sitemap_follow` in the following way, since [the spiders documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) says that this variable expects to receive a list.

```
>>> sitemap_follow = ['^.$']
```

But then the same page of documentation says, 'By default, all sitemaps are followed.' Thus, this would appear to be entirely unnecessary.

**I wonder what you are trying to do.**

EDIT: In response to a comment. You might be able to do this using what is called a 'negative lookbehind assertion', in this cases that's the `(?<!image-)`. My reservation about this is that you need to be able to scan over stuff like abc.com at the beginnings of the URLs which could present quite fascinating challenges.

```
>>> for s in sitemap_index_file_content:
...     m = re.match(r'[^\/]*\/(?<!image-)sitemap.*', s)
...     if m:
...         m.group()
... 
'abc.com/sitemap-1.xml'
'abc.com/sitemap-2.xml'
```

Comment: Either I was too tired or SO ate part of my question. I want to avoid reading image-sitemap but only sitemap-xxx. that is wy i tried with ^sitemap.

Comment: I suppose we should check how Scrapy uses the regex. I was thinking it only check the path and not the  url. Otherwise an easier solution should be to use the crawler only on abc.com so that the regex will have that part fixed

Comment: That would be ideal but you never know. I think you'd be best to check, as you've suggested yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One option to skip urls is to override sitemap_filter() on your class:

```
  class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "scraperapi_sitemap"
    
    /* Your current code goes here ... */

    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        """This method can be used to filter sitemap entries by their
        attributes, for example, you can filter locs with lastmod greater
        than a given date or (see docs) or skipping by complex regex.
        """
        image_url_pattern = '.*/image-.*'
        for entry in entries:
            result = re.match(image_url_pattern, entry['loc'])
            if result:
                logging.info("Skipping "+ str(entry))
            else:
                yield entry
```